# Add a text field to OG subscription form

Tags: entities, organic-groups

I would like to add a text field to the `og_ui_confirm_subscribe` form so that applicants can motivate their request to the owner of the group.

I don't have any problem to create the field and attach it to this form through a simple `hook_form_alter` but **I am lost once I have to link the text field to the user of the OG admin**...

I've googled but it doesn't seem to be a highly requested feature (only a - brief - mention found in [OG 4.7](http://drupal.org/node/84181) but this didn't led any further. It's weird since it means that admin are supposed to accept/deny only based on username...

By the way, these OG admin pages are very poor in terms of UI so I might think customizing them with Views & VBO; would this direction be a good way to go to easily get my text field?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed it is possible to add this field (and others if needed) through the OG settings of the membership (cf. `admin/config/group/group-membership/manage/NAME_OF_YOUR_OG_MEMBERSHIP/fields`).